# Unable to create link to other activity?

Tags: android

i am new to android i am unable to create link from my current list view to other activities:
This is my code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_advanced_main);
        ListView lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("image", R.drawable.mj_icon);
        map.put("text1", "Michael Jackson");
        map.put("text2", "King Of Pop");
        map.put("to",R.drawable.arrow_icon );
        mylist.add(map);
        map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map.put("image", R.drawable.sachin_icon);
        map.put("text1", "Sachin Tendulkar");
        map.put("text2", "The Master Blaster");
        map.put("to",R.drawable.arrow_icon );
        mylist.add(map);
        map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map.put("image", R.drawable.hrithik_icon);
        map.put("text1", "Hrithik Roshan");
        map.put("text2", "Bollywood Actor");
        map.put("to",R.drawable.arrow_icon );
        mylist.add(map);
        map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
       map.put("image", R.drawable.maradona_icon);
        map.put("text1", "Diego Maradona");
        map.put("text2", "The God Of Soccer");
        map.put("to",R.drawable.arrow_icon);
        mylist.add(map);


        SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.list_advanced,
                new String[] {"image", "text1", "text2", "to"}, new int[] {R.id.movieicon, R.id.name, R.id.description, R.id.img});


        setListAdapter(mSchedule);

       lv1=getListView();
        lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id){

                switch(position)
                {
                case 0:
                Intent obj = new Intent(advancedlistview.this,michaeljackson.class);
                startActivityForResult(obj,0);
                Log.i("test","tst");
                break;
                case 1:

              Intent obj1 = new Intent(advancedlistview.this,Sachin.class);
                System.out.println("hello");
              startActivity(obj1); 
            break;
                case 2:
                     Intent obj2 = new Intent(advancedlistview.this,Hrithik.class);
                    startActivity(obj2); 
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Intent obj3 = new Intent(advancedlistview.this,Maradona.class);
                    startActivity(obj3);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

My log cat is::

03-03 12:35:05.093: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4899): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-03 12:35:05.093: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4899): CheckJNI is ON
03-03 12:35:05.632: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4899): --- registering native functions ---
03-03 12:35:07.531: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4899): Shutting down VM
03-03 12:35:07.563: DEBUG/dalvikvm(4899): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-03 12:35:07.563: INFO/AndroidRuntime(4899): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-03 12:35:08.950: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4909): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-03 12:35:08.950: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4909): CheckJNI is ON
03-03 12:35:09.585: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4909): --- registering native functions ---
03-03 12:35:11.784: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.ex.dp/.demoProject1 }
03-03 12:35:11.877: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4909): Shutting down VM
03-03 12:35:11.877: INFO/AndroidRuntime(4909): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-03 12:35:11.877: DEBUG/dalvikvm(4909): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-03 12:35:15.608: DEBUG/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
03-03 12:40:15.687: DEBUG/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
03-03 12:45:15.735: DEBUG/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

My console is giving error:

[2011-03-03 12:35:08 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:571)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:670)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

Comment: What is the error? Please provide the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your classes listed in the AndroidManifest.xml file?
[Android Manifest Info](http://wrenbjor.com/2011/01/12/the-androidmanifest-xml-file/)

Each Activity has to be in the manifest or the app will crash. Try This:

```
<activity android:name=".michaeljackson" android:label="michaeljackson" />
<activity android:name=".Sachin" android:label="Sachin" />
<activity android:name=".Hrithik" android:label="Hrithik" />
<activity android:name=".Maradona" android:label="Maradona" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your context is incorrect. Try switching

```
advancedlistview.this
```

for

```
getApplicationContext();
```

If that doesn't work, please post your stack trace.

Edit: you have a comma in your first startActivityForResult(obj --> , <-- 0) I dont think you meant to have that there. Also, try using curly brackets in your switch statement to separate the blocks.

Comment: Do you know where the logcat is? If you're running eclipse it should be in the debug perspective. You should find some information about the error in there, try pasting the bits you deem relevant in here.

Comment: 03-03 11:57:16.813: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(3828): No keyboard for id 0
03-03 11:57:16.844: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(3828): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

Comment: What happens when you click?  A "stack trace" is the record that the Java VM records if your app crashes. It is written to a log seen via the logcat view: in Eclipse, menu Window, Show View > Other, folder Android, logcat.  Look for many red log lines, together, beginning with *Exception, and paste in the whole set here.  If it doesn't crash, what does it do?

Comment: I am also getting NullPointer Exception in console

Comment: i am not getting any excepyion in log cat but in console i am getting this:

Comment: 2011-03-03 11:56:44 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:571)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:670)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

Comment: The click is not generating on the item